# Can I pass an array into a Google App Script method from a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

Can I pass an array into a Google App Script method from a Google Spreadsheet?

Suppose I have an App Script function that expects a list with two elements (note: this example is just an example so please do not tell me that my problem would be solved if I simply passed each element as a separate argument). How do I call this function from a Google Spreadsheet cell?

I've tried both: '=myFunc([1,2])' and '=myFunc((1,2))' and both give me a Parse Error.

Comment: The vector values ​​are in cells of the sheet? Can you pass a range, `=myFunc(A1:A2)`?

Comment: They are not necessarily values in the sheet's cells. Even if they were, your suggestion requires the values to be in a contiguous range, which is something I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a spreadsheet formula, you can construct an embedded array using curly braces. Semi-colons are row delimiters; commas (or backslashes in locales that use a comma for the decimal separator) are column delimiters.

Now when such embedded arrays are passed to Google Apps Script, they are converted to a 2-dimensional Javascript array, just like referenced ranges are.

So:

`=myFunc({1,2})`

`=myFunc({1;2})`

```
function myFunc(value)
{
}
```

In the first formula, `value` will be `[[1, 2]]`. In the second, it will be `[[1], [2]]`.

Comment: Very good choice. Using text would be: `=myFunc({"test, comma", 1, "another test; with ""quote"""})`

Comment: Look carefully those cases where you have a single value, for example: `=myFunc({1})`, for the moment, the behavior is not as expected, looking for options to fix it.

Comment: Passing a single value `=myFunc({1})`, the parameter received is not a array, is the value itself.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to pass a string of text and then transform it into an array inside the function myFunc:

```
function myFunc(value) {
  var arr = value.split(',');
}

=myFunc("1,2")
```

or

```
function myFunc(value) {
  /* remember you have to be careful with this function: eval() */
  var arr = eval(value);
}

=myFunc("[1,2]")
```

Comment: This is useful but what if the values that I want to pass in contain commas? Is there a way to quote them so that they won't be parsed as split tokens?

Comment: you can use any other separator, try one that will never be used in normal text | I like this one |

Comment: The choice of eval() can handle that case, but then, you must address the risks of using eval(). `=myFunc("['test, comma', 1, 'other, test']")`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a selected range of cells into your Javascript function like so:

[image]

The Javascript function will be invoked, and the values will be passed to a singe parameter as the following:

```
[[""],[""],["E3"],[""],["E1"],[""],[""],[""]]
```

This array of arrays can be normalized, using a simple `map` and `filter` chaining:

```js
function calculateSalaryMultiple(values) {

  // values == [[""],[""],["E3"],[""],["E1"],[""],[""],[""]]
  values = values.map(x=>x[0]).filter(x=>x);

  // values == ["E3", "E1"]
  // Rest of your logic
  ...
```