# JS Code works on other editors but not Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote the following code for a Google Sheet:

```
var cost = [50, 100];
var payee = "Dave";
var payer = ["Dave", "David"];
var result = calcPayable(payee, cost, payer);
function calcPayable(payee, cost, payer) {
    var totalPayable = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cost.length; i++) {
        if (payer[i] === payee) {
            totalPayable += (cost[i] / 5);
        }
    }
    return totalPayable;
}
console.log(result);
```

It essentially splits the cost of a trip between 5 people.
The problem I've been having is that it doesn't work on Google Apps Script, it gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 3, file "Code")". Note that the variables outside the function is for testing purposes. However, while running the same code on playcode.io, the code works fine. I am new to JS but have worked with Java and Python previously, so I could be doing something wrong.

EDIT: This is the actual script code, the above was something I used for testing in playcode.io

```
function calcPayable(payee, cost, payer) {
    var totalPayable = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cost.length; i++) {
        if (payer[i] === payee) {
            totalPayable += (cost[i] / 5);
        }
    }
    return totalPayable;
}
```

EDIT 2: I forgot to mention that payee is a string, cost is a FP array, and payer is a string arrray. These would be passed in by calling the function =costPayable(F3,B2:B18,C2:C18).

EDIT 3: Problem was the comparison operator that I used (should have been == not ===), not GAS. This proves, as always, that to assume = to make an ass out of you and me.

Thanks to all those who devoted some of their precious time to answering this noob question!

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with your code. Seems like an environment issue.

Comment: Which line is line 3 file "Code"? (it looks like the error comes from other place, not from the code shown in the question)

Comment: The error is saying you called `calcPayable` like this: `calcPayable(payee, undefined, payer)`. I'm sure you didn't literally write `undefined`, but that's whatever you are passing in is being evaluated to at run time.

Comment: In your case, when put a script of `function sample() {}` to your script editor and run the function of `sample`, I think that the result of your script can be seen at the log without the error. Because at Google APps Script, the script is run by selecting a function. In this case, `var result = calcPayable(payee, cost, payer)` is run as global. This has already been mentioned by @dwmorrin 's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened here is that Google Apps Script will run the function in your script automatically, and the reason the error happened is due to the fact that your `calcPayable` function actually runs TWICE (once when you called console.log(result) within your script, and a second time when the function is automatically called by Google Apps Script).

Due to the fact that no parameters were passed to the `calcPayable` function the second time it is run, you receive an undefined error.

You can actually confirm this issue by assigning default parameter values to your function, so the second time the function is run (without parameters), it will not return undefined error, like this:

```
var cost = [50, 100];
var payee = "Dave";
var payer = ["Dave", "David"];
var result = calcPayable(payee, cost, payer);

function calcPayable(payee = "Dave", cost = [50, 100], payer = ["Dave", "David"]) {
    var totalPayable = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cost.length; i++) {
        if (payer[i] === payee) {
            totalPayable += (cost[i] / 5);
        }
    }
    return totalPayable;
}

console.log(result);
```

EDIT: Created a Google Sheet with your function and it is working as intended, although you have to replace `payer[i] === payee` with `payer[i] == payee` as `===` checks for type.

[image]

```
function calcPayable(payee, cost, payer) {
    var totalPayable = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cost.length; i++) {
        if (payer[i] == payee) {
            totalPayable += (cost[i] / 5);
        }
    }
    return totalPayable;
}
```

Note: You have to run your function within Google Sheets and not directly from GAS script editor

Comment: The console.log and the variables above the function are just for testing purposes, the actual script is only the function. When I run the function without the first 4 variables and the console.log, it still gives me the TypeError error, hence the Line 3 where it seems to think the array is undefined.

Comment: If that’s the case the issue might be that you are not passing an array as the `cost` parameter. In order to pass an array in Google Sheet, you have to wrap them in curly braces. More info on passing arrays to GAS from Google Sheet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18312416)

Comment: Just tried that, and it still doesn't work. However, I am trying to pass a list of cells through the function by calling =calcPayment(F3,B2:B18,C2:C18) where F3 is the name of the payee, B2:B18 is the cost, and C2:C18 is the payer, but AFAIK it should automatically convert into an array and passed through the function?

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue and your function seems to be running without errors. Edited my answer above.

Comment: Ah, that was the problem. So the TypeError was not the problem, and the comparison operator was. I probably should've tried replacing that as a first troubleshooting step, but as I was new to JS but had Java experience, I assumed (incorrectly) that == would not work, proving the old saying that "to assume = to make an 'ass' out of 'u' and 'me'". Anyways, thank you so much for your time and expertise in solving the results of my stupidity!